# Obfuscate text and preserve line breaks

Tags: c#, strings

**Problem**

A function is needed, that obfuscates text but preserves line breaks. Line breaks may be encoded by `"\r\n"` or `"\r"`, even mixed. `myObfuscator` is an object that obfuscates text, ignoring line breaks (would be replaced by any other character).

**Example:**

> ABC\r\nDEF\rGHE

should be obfuscated to something like

> XXX\r\nXXX\rXXX

where XXX depends on `myObfuscator` (not important for the question).

**Implementation**

My approach works, but seems a little too complicated.

```
public string Obfuscate(string text)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var lineCount = 0;
    var lines = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var innerLineCount = 0;
        if (lineCount > 0) stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
        foreach (var innerLine in line.Split(new[] { "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        {
            if (innerLineCount > 0) stringBuilder.Append("\r");
            var obfuscatedLine = string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerLine) ? string.Empty : myObfuscator.Obfuscate(innerLine);
            stringBuilder.Append(obfuscatedLine);
            innerLineCount++;
        }
        lineCount++;
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simple text manipulation task is perfect for regular expressions.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Tests
{
    public static class StringUtils
    {
        public delegate string Obfuscate(string str);

        public static string ObfuscateLines(string str, Obfuscate obfuscate)
            => new Regex(@"[^\r\n]+").Replace(str, match => obfuscate(match.Value));
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class ObfuscatorTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestObfuscate()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("A\r\nLLLL\rSSSSSSSSS",
                StringUtils.ObfuscateLines(
                    "A\r\nLong\rSentence.",
                    line => new string(line[0], line.Length)));

            Assert.AreEqual("XXX\r\nXXX\rXXX",
                StringUtils.ObfuscateLines(
                    "A\r\nLong\rSentence.",
                    line => "XXX"));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know C# very well, therefore I did not manage to do the same code with `Obfuscator` being an `interface`, but I'm sure you can find out.

Comment: So nice and short with regex ;-]

Comment: I added a working regex based solution to my answer. :)

Comment: Great solution, thanks! :). That I don't come up with such obvious solutions myself -.-.

Answer (score 6):

I would omit the `StringBuilder` here and would go with `string.Join()` by joining the processed `innerLines` and the processed `lines` like so

```
public string Obfuscate(string text)
{

    var lines = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {

        var innerLines = lines[i].Split(new[] { "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        for (int j = 0; j < innerLines.Length; j++)
        {
            innerLines[j]= string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerLines[j]) ? string.Empty : myObfuscator.Obfuscate(innerLines[j]);
        }

        lines[i] = string.Join("\r", innerLines);

    }
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);

}
```

What I would add about your code would be some proper argument validation because the method is `public`. In addition I would move the check wether ther `innerLine` is `NullOrEmpty` inside the obfuscator.

Comment: Reusing the arrays and moving the "is string null or empty check" to the obfuscater is a good idea. I will do it that way - thanks :).

Answer (score 4):

You could use single loop and a buffer that you obfuscate and empty each time you find either a `\r` or `\n`. Then you can fix the line breaks and join the strings again:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Obfuscate(string text)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in text)
    {
        if(IsNewLine(c) && buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return Obfuscator.Obfuscate(buffer.ToString());
            buffer.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.Append(c);
        }
    }

    if (buffer.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return Obfuscator.Obfuscate(buffer.ToString());       
    }

    bool IsNewLine(char c) => c == '\r' || c == '\n';
}
```

---

Preserving line beraks is also relitively easy. You just need to change the `foreach` into a `while` and use an enumerator that you can pass to the `ReadLineBreaks` method that will continue reading line break chars. Unlike your method, this one will also consume line breaks at the and of a string.

```
public static string Obfuscate(string text)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    using (var enumerator = text.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (IsNewLine(enumerator.Current) && buffer.Length > 0)
            {
                result.Append(Obfuscator.Obfuscate(buffer.ToString()));
                result.Append(ReadLineBreaks(enumerator, out var moveNext));
                buffer.Clear();
                if (moveNext)
                {
                    buffer.Append(enumerator.Current);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                buffer.Append(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }

        if (buffer.Length > 0)
        {
            result.Append(Obfuscator.Obfuscate(buffer.ToString()));
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

private static string ReadLineBreaks(IEnumerator<char> enumerator, out bool moveNext)
{
    moveNext = false;
    var lineBreaks = new StringBuilder();
    while (IsNewLine(enumerator.Current))
    {
        lineBreaks.Append(enumerator.Current);
        moveNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (!moveNext) break;
    }
    return lineBreaks.ToString();
}

private static bool IsNewLine(char c) => c == '\r' || c == '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach with the buffer. Do you think that solution is more readable / elegant than the code in the question?

Answer (score 2):

If the obfuscation is strictly dependent upon the character being obfuscated (i.e., `a` always maps to `L`) and all of the non-obfuscated characters need to remain as-is (i.e., `\r\n` and `\r` need to remain the same in the output), the following works:

```
public string ObfuscateWrapper(string original, Func<char, char> obfuscator, char[] ignoreChars = null) {
    ignoreChars = ignoreChars ?? new char[] { };
    return new String(original.ToCharArray().Select(c => ignoreChars.Contains(c) ? c : obfuscator(c)).ToArray());
}
```

If you want to normalize the line endings, I'd suggest doing that elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could just separate out all the "valid" characters, apply obfuscation, and then put them back. In Python this could be implemented as:

```
import pandas as pd
# Turn the string into a Series of characters
string_series = pd.Series([ch for ch in string_to_be_obfuscated])
# Create a Series of Booleans keeping track of whether 
#    the character at that index is a character you want obfuscated
character_index = ((string_series != "\r") & (string_series != "\n"))
# Slice the string Series to get characters you want obfuscated
#    and obfuscate just those characters
obfuscated_series = myObfuscator.Obfuscate(string_series[character_index])
# You might need to modify either the above line or your obfuscator 
#     if the formats are incompatible
# Put the obfuscated characters back in the original Series at the
#    indices of the characters you obfuscated
string_series[character_index] = obfuscated_series
# Now put string_series in whatever format you want your output to be
```

This assumes by "preserve line breaks", you mean "keeps line breaks in the same place", not "obfuscate each line separately".

Comment: OP tagged C#, not Python. Would down vote, but I don't have the rep.

Comment: @Simon Arsenault Whether a downvote is appropriate depends on whether the OP primarily wants code, or an approach. I presented an algorithm, explained what each step does, and presented Python code as an example.

Comment: You can write it in a one liner: `var obfuscatedText = new string(text.Select(i => new[] { '\n', '\r' }.Contains(i) ? i : obfuscater.Obfuscate(i.ToString())[0]).ToArray())`. However, as you mentioned, the restriction is that each character will be obfuscated separately.